# Calling SOAP webwervice from a javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is there any method of calling a SOAP Service with the URL :

```
http://localhost:8088/...TestService?wsdl
```

How can I invoke and get the values from the client using javascript?

Cheers!!

Thanks

Comment: did you get a chance to search Google ? I just used your question's heading and can see http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/ . Below this URL I see 2 links of SE itself .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt call soap service directly from js because soap is not limited to http communication and there is no good support for soap in JavaScript.
It is better to use intermediate layer which is more capable in terms of soap communication. For example you can call from JavaScript your asp.net mvc application using ajax and then call soap service from asp.net mvc app using wcf. Instead of asp.net mvc you can use any other server side technology and soap communication library. JavaScript is good for ajax/json communication but not for soap.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have a SOAP library out of the box, though you can google around and find them,  The web services still need to be on the origin server.

Similar Question found

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577237/how-to-use-soap-in-javascript)